# ffmpeg stuck in generating thumbnail of video

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, quicktime

I'm currently writing a script to create thumbnails of videos in a folder, but as soon as ffmpeg hits a .mov video, it gets stuck. The videos were taken on an iphone at 4k 60fps and can be played back without a problem, so I know they are not corrupted.
For the extraction of the picture I tried the same command on 2 different machines and with different types of arguments, but nothing changed the result.

What I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_1001.MOV -ss 00:00:02 -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg
```

It gets stuck at the third last line `frame= 0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x` and from then on, I stopped the process with ctrl+c

Output:
`ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_1001.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 8
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 13.2.2
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-11-xx
  Duration: 00:00:05.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 54961 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 54851 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : HEVC
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 94 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55d83a288940] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'thumbnail.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-11-xx
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 8
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 13.2.2
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 3840x2160, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-xx
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

Any idea on what it could be? Am I missing something or could it be that the encoding can't be read properly by ffmpeg? Besides that I haven't found any alternative to generate thumbnails from videos on linux

Comment: 3.4 is old. Try a [recent version](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (*git master* preferable over *release*) before trying anything else.

Comment: Thank you! With the newest static build it didn't get stuck anymore ...but why is the build in the ubuntu repo so old?

Comment: That is how packages generally work in non-rolling release distros (if it isn't backported). Ubuntu 18.04 is from early 2018, and packages are generally not continuously updated. Some users view that as a benefit and consider it more stable. Although this is changing somewhat with the introduction of snap. If you want to have new packages always available I recommend using a rolling release like Arch Linux or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I just used an old version of ffmpeg (that is in the debian repository). Downloading a [recent static build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and using that one instead solved the stuck problem.